# Lighttpd mod_secdownload gives 404 error

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, lighttpd, clipbucket

I am developing site under Clipbucket cms. I am trying to stream videos via lighttpd :81, and rest website operated via httpd.

Now I am able to change port and now videos are working correctly, now I am trying to add sec_download mod. in code. The issue is I am able to get url in correct format  like `<uri-prefix>/<token>/<timestamp-in-hex>/<rel-path>`
But when I open videos in browser in debug it shows 404 not found error. 
I am thinking server is actually looking for that dynamic folder that is created with link, but its just a virtual link right?

How do I enable this dynamic link, understanding in server? Do I have to rewrite in `.htaccess`?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are going to have to write htaccess rule to redirect that URL and load your video files. By default, ClipBucket URL are accessed directly (no secure streaming at the moment) and strings that you are providing in URL are confusing CB and hence, it can pick the video file.

Hope that helps.